# .gitignore check part name to folder to ignore all file and subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

this is a question:
the path of folder is:

```
/program/example_data/code
/program/example1_data/code
/program/example2_data/code
/program/example3_data/bin
```

Goal -> Ignore all subfolder and file in _data. Check a part of name (_data)
I add to file .ignore this istruction

```
**/*_data/
```

But not work. It is possible check a part of name ?
Thanks you

Comment: I've ran a little test, and `**/*_data/` works fine for me. Are you sure `.gitignore` is present in the right directory?

Comment: yes. is present. full path is /Project/program/example_data/code. in Project is present to .gitignore and .git but when commit and push not update to select file to gitExtension

Comment: Now Run -> the problem was the files and subfolder are present in to server. Delete file in to local and commit push -> recreate a file and subfolder and Now not check a new file and subfolder contain in _data ... Thank You